# How does Apache webserver is able to detect CNAME

Tags: apache-httpd, dns, ip, apache-virtualhost, ip-address

I was quite curious how does Apache web server can detect a subdomain even when all the subdomains point to same IP address, since my understanding is that an IP address that cannot have a subdomain, and every domain name ultimately resolve to an IP address.

Example:

```
example1.domain.com resolves to => 192.24.17.65 take you to => example1 webpage

example2.domain.com resolves to => 192.24.17.65 take you to => example2 webpage
```

Comment: See the `Host` HTTP request header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed true that in the early years of the web, hosting multiple websites (different domains, subdomains of a single domain, etc) off a single IP was infeasible.

However, in 1999, the transition to HTTP 1.1 began, and today HTTP 1.0 is rarely used (in fact HTTP 2 has become widespread but 1.1 is still common).

HTTP 1.1 requests include a Host: header that allows the browser to specify the domain it's trying to reach.

You can easily see this with curl, using the verbose flag to view the request you're sending:

```
# curl -Iv http://google.com/
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4025:402::64:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (2a00:1450:4025:402::64) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

The migration to encrypted websites (HTTPS, using SSL/TLS) complicated things, because the encryption handshake must happen before the HTTP rest (including Host: header) is sent, but multiple sites hosted from the same IP might use different encryption certificates.

The current solution to this is SNI (Server Name Indication), an extension to TLS that is conceptually similar to the Host header:  the requesting browser send the domain it's trying to connect to to the server early in the connection attempt so that the server can complete the encryption handshake properly.

Answer (score 1):

On name-based virtual hosts, Apache is using the [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) and [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) directives to match the HTTP request's `Host` header against the specified domain name after matching the IP address and port.

If no `ServerName` / `ServerAlias` matches, then the first listed (default) virtual host matching the IP address and port gets the request.

Related:

- [Name-based Virtual Host Support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) (Apache Documentation)